# Benchmarking C struct comparsion: XOR vs ==

Tags: c, performance, x86, comparison, benchmarking

Say we have a simple struct in C that has 4 fields:

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
} value_st;
```

Let's take a look at these two short versions of C struct equal check.

The first one is straight-forward and does the following:

```
int compare1(const value_st *x1, const value_st *x2) {
    return ( (x1->a == x2->a) && (x1->b == x2->b) &&
             (x1->c == x2->c) && (x1->d == x2->d) );
}
```

The second one uses **XOR**:

```
int compare2(const value_st *x1, const value_st *x2) {
    return ( (x1->a ^ x2->a) | (x1->b ^ x2->b) |
             (x1->c ^ x2->c) | (x1->d ^ x2->d); 
}
```

The first version will return **nonzero** if both structs are equal.

and the second version will return **zero** iff the two structs are equal.

### Compiler Output

Compiling with GCC -O2 and examining the assembly looks like what we expect.

The first version is 4 CMP instructions and JMPS:

```
xor    %eax,%eax
mov    (%rsi),%edx
cmp    %edx,(%rdi)
je     0x9c0 <compare1+16>
repz   retq 
nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
mov    0x4(%rsi),%ecx
cmp    %ecx,0x4(%rdi)
jne    0x9b8 <compare1+8>
mov    0x8(%rsi),%ecx
cmp    %ecx,0x8(%rdi)
jne    0x9b8 <compare1+8>
mov    0xc(%rsi),%eax
cmp    %eax,0xc(%rdi)
sete   %al
movzbl %al,%eax
retq
```

The second version looks like this:

```
mov    (%rdi),%eax
mov    0x4(%rdi),%edx
xor    (%rsi),%eax
xor    0x4(%rsi),%edx
or     %edx,%eax
mov    0x8(%rdi),%edx
xor    0x8(%rsi),%edx
or     %edx,%eax
mov    0xc(%rdi),%edx
xor    0xc(%rsi),%edx
or     %edx,%eax
retq
```

So the **second** version has:

- no branches
- less instructions

### Benchmarking

```
static uint64_t
now_msec() {
    struct timespec spec;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &spec);
    return ((uint64_t)spec.tv_sec * 1000) + (spec.tv_nsec / 1000000);
}

void benchmark() {
    uint64_t start = now_msec();
    uint64_t sum = 0;

    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < 1e10; i++) {
        if (compare1(&x1, &x2)) {
            sum++;
        }
    }

    uint64_t delta_ms = now_msec() - start;

    // use sum and delta here
}
```

Enough iterations to filter out the time it takes to call clock_gettime()

But here is the thing I don't get...

When I benchmark **equal** structs where all the instructions need to be executed,
the first version is faster...

```
time took for compare == is 3114 [ms]   [matches: 10000000000]
time took for compare XOR is 3177 [ms]  [matches: 10000000000]
```

How is this possible ?
Even with branch prediction, XOR should be super fast instruction and
not lose to CMP/JMP

### Update

Couple of important notes:

- This question is mainly to **understand** the outcome. not to try to beat the compiler or create an obscure code - it is always better to write clean code and let the compiler optimize
- We assume the structs are in the **cache**, otherwise the **dominating** factor will be obviously the memory lookup
- Branch prediction will obviously play a part...but can it be better than branchless code (given that most of the time we execute all the code) ?
- `memcmp` will require zero padding in the struct and also might need a loop / if in most standard implementations, as it supports variable size comparison

### Update 2

- Many have stated that the **difference** is tiny per call...this is true but is **consistent** which means that this difference is in favor of the first version in many consecutive runs

### Update 3

I've copied my test code to a lab server with a `Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v3 @ 3.20GHz`
The XOR version runs almost two times faster on the server for GCC 8.

Tried with both clang and GCC 8:

For GCC 8:

```
time took for compare == is 7432 [ms]    [matches: 3000000000]
time took for compare XOR is 4214 [ms]   [matches: 3000000000]
```

for Clang:

```
time took for compare == is 4265 [ms]    [matches: 3000000000]
time took for compare XOR is 5508 [ms]   [matches: 3000000000]
```

So it seems like this is very compiler and CPU dependent.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226375/discussion-on-question-by-itay-marom-benchmarking-c-struct-comparsion-xor-vs).

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the first case there are 4 mov's and 4 cmp's. In the second case there are 4 mov's, 4 xor's *and* 4 or's. As jmp's not taken take in effect no time, the first version *is* faster. (cmp and xor do basically the same thing and should execute in the same amount of time)

The moral of the story here is that you should never try to outsmart your compiler, it really knows better (at least in 99.99% of cases)

And never obscure the intent of your program in an effort to make it faster, unless you have hard evidence it is (1) needed and (2) effective.

Comment: It's true that `cmp/jne` macro-fuse into a single compare-and-branch uop, and that since it's not-taken it can run on 2 execution units in the back-end of Intel Haswell/Skylake. (https://agner.org/optimize/).  Saying that it costs nothing "because it's not-taken" is an over-simplification.  BTW, note that `xor` and `or` *can't* macro-fuse with a JCC, so the final `or`/`jnz` (after this inlines) is 2 separate uops for the front-end.

Comment: But more likely the loop-invariant comparison gets hoisted out of the loop entirely, so it's just incrementing a counter and doing no other work; as Hans commented, the total times aren't long enough for more than a single cycle per loop iteration, and the stand-alone non-inlined code shown is more than 4 or 5 uops for either version, even if data stays hot in registers instead of having to be loaded from memory.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> time took for compare == is 3114 [ms]   [matches: 10000000000]
> time took for compare XOR is 3177 [ms]  [matches: 10000000000]
> ```
>
> How is this possible ?

Because actual execution time is affected by *many* factors out of your control, which is why you should never rely on a *single* run of a benchmarking program to make any decisions.  Run it many times, under different load conditions, and average the results.

Secondly, this run shows a difference of 63 *milliseconds* out of a little over 3 seconds, or 2%, for *one billion* comparisons between the two methods.  As far as a person sitting in front of the screen is concerned, that's *barely* noticable.  If your results consistently showed a difference of a full second or more that would be worth investigating, but this is down in the noise.

And finally, what is going to be the more common operation *in the real code* - comparing identical structs or non-identical structs?  If the second case is going to be more common, even if just by a bare majority of 51%, then the `==` method will be *significantly* faster on average due to short-circuiting.

When optimizing code, look at the big picture - don't hyperfocus on a single operation.  You'll wind up writing code that's hard to read, harder to maintain, and probably not as optimized as you think it is.

Comment: Not saying the 2% is huge but it is **consistent**. meaning that across many runs, the first version is **always** faster....not by a lot but always

Comment: also, for your last comment:
I am not planning to write this code in production....I still think it is intriguing...the results are not intuitive...

Comment: @John: It's not necessarily a safe assumption that short-circuited compare/branch will be faster.  If they almost always differ (so the branchless version would be predictable), but some differ in the first and some in the second element, in an unpredictable way, you will get more branch misses from the short-circuit version than the branchless version, so the extra work could pay for itself, especially if the front-end is already (almost) a bottleneck. You have to benchmark; modern branch predictors are amazing so even knowing your data doesn't tell you if predictors will figure it out or not